# Cassandra bulk insertion using Binary memtable (BMT) or storage proxy

Tags: java, cassandra, bulkinsert

i want to bulk insert to cassandra using storage proxy or Binary memtable (BMT) in java ,but i am not able to find any documentation ,API or example of the same ,could anyone help?

Thanks and regards 
samarth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you some reference on this:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading